# Porque no me detecta que he instalado minecraft_launcher_lib

Tags: python, tkinter, minecraft-forge

estoy intentando crear un Launcher de minecraft con tkinter y la librería de minecraft_launcher_lib, pero no entiendo el porque no detecta que tengo minecraft_launcher_lib instalado, para instalar la librería use este comando: pip install minecraft-launcher-lib pero solo me aparece estas líneas cuando lo instalo

[image: Captura de la instalación]
[image: Captura del error]
[image: Codigo del launcher]

Si hay alguien que me pueda ayudar se lo agradecería

Comment: Eso solo parece ser problema del linter, si ejecutas el programa obtienes algún error?

Comment: Si me sale este error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h:\launcher minecraft\patata.py", line 3, in <module>
    import minecraft_launcher_lib as mcl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'minecraft_launcher_lib'

Comment: Estas trabajando en algún entorno virtual?

Comment: Hice pruebas con `pip install minecraft-launcher-lib` tanto en python 3.10, como en 3.11 (normal y venv) y se instaló e importó correctamente. Sugiero instales antes un paquete llamado [wheel](https://pythonwheels.com/), de esta forma python descarga los binarios de las librerías directamente sin tener que compilarlos, claro, si existen.

Comment: No estoy trabajando en un entorno virtual sino en mi pc personal y lo de wheel lo instale y me sigue fallando

Comment: El código debe ir en formato texto y no en imagen, incluyendo el mensaje o mensajes de error. Haz clic en [edit] y cambia lo que haga falta. Saludos